# Count total number paths in tree length wise

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, big-o

Given a tree with `n` nodes, find the total number of paths of length `k` in that tree for each `k` in range from `0` to `n-1`.

I know I can loop [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119768/count-total-number-of-k-length-paths-in-a-tree) for `k` in the given range but that will make it a **O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)** solution.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There is a O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution:

1. **Create list** `P` of length `n` to store the answer.
2. For **every vertex** `v` in the tree do a **DFS** (or BFS if you like) and **update** `P` with the `paths` starting at `v`.
3. For **every position** of `P` except `P[0]` **divide** its **value** by `2`.

**Time complexity**
Step 1: O(n)
Step 2: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
Step 3: O(n)
Overall runtime: O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Note: 3rd step is only needed if paths `u` to `v` and `v` to `u` are considered the same path. `P[0]` is not divided by `2` as there are only `n` zero length paths and they are not counted twice (same start and end vertex).